# How do I change numbering from arabic letters to roman letters after ToC and set countering to 1?

Tags: page-numbering, front-matter

I am trying to change the numbering from roman to Arabic after my Table of Contents. So far I found out that I need those two things:

- `\pagenumbering{roman}`
- `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

But I am not quite sure where to put them and how to edit the count of numbers. I need to start from 1 again after table of contents. This is my code so far:

```
\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}

\input{title page}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\cleardoublepage\stepcounter{blankpages}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}

\tableofcontents

   \pagenumbering{arabic}

   \input{chapter1.tex}

   \input{chapter2.tex}

   \input{chapter3.tex}

   \input{chapter4.tex}

   \input{chapter5.tex}

   \input{chapter6.tex}

   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Table of figures}}

   \listoffigures

   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{bibliography}

   \mbox{}

   \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So to sum up my question: I wanna have counting in Roman until ToC (ToC included) and after the ToC, Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc. in Arabic plus starting from 1 again.

Comment: Normally one would use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` but you do not show any preamble or document class, so we have no idea whether your setup supports it

Comment: My preamble looks like the following:

[Preamble code[1]


  [1]: https://pastebin.com/Mi4zXR9U

Comment: Update your question, we do not want to go to external sources. External links have a tendency to rot over time thus making your question unusable for othes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{chapter1.tex}

% ...
```

for the page number of the first chapter in `chapter1.tex` to start on page 1. The key here is to use `\cleardoublepage` so you're on the correct (recto) page for a chapter. That way `\pagenumbering{arabic}` would reset the page number on the page you want.

<sub>Be aware that resetting the page numbering might cause issues when using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It worked out pretty well.

Comment: @Fendi: Consider accepting the answer as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)